# Как поместить в файл в коллекцию?

Tags: java

Ввести строки из файла ,записать в список.Вывести данные файла в обратном порядке

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Tatiana\\Documents\\nr.txt");
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(file);

    String line = " ";
    while ((line = f.readLine()) != null) {


        // ArrayList<String>f1=new ArrayList<String>();
        Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(line));
        System.out.println(line);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Это какое-то алгоритмическое задание? Можно воспользоваться утилитарным методом [`Files.readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

Answer (score 0):

В чём у вас конкретно проблема? Или вы ждете готовое решение?

Инициируйте коллекцию вне первого цикла. В первом цикле считываете по строкам и помещаете каждую строку в коллекцию (line). Потом вне цикла делайте реверс. Во втором цикле выводите.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/514442)

Comment: @Doofy прочитайте дальше второго вопроса плиз, там содержится ответ.

Comment: Ну так вопросы нужно задавать в комментариях. А ответы в ответах